# How to Make MultiRows on swiper/react

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to use swiper/react library from "Swiperjs", i was following the documentation here: 
https://swiperjs.com/react 
and I want to make multirows like this one :

https://swiperjs.com/demos/170-grid/core

```
import Categorie from "../Categorie/Categorie";
import "./categories.css";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/css";

const Categories = () => {
  return (
    <section className="categories">
      <Swiper slidesPerView={5} spaceBetween={5} grabCursor={true}>
        {[...Array(20)].map((categ, i) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={i}>
            <Categorie />
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Categories;
```

do I miss some options of swiper ?.

Answer (score 0):

please use Grid module. The example is built using the grid module.  https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#grid